# How to bind to UpdateSourceTrigger in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, updatesourcetrigger

I need to bind to the UpdateSourceTrigger property. I have a class with

```
public UpdateSourceTrigger trigger {get ; set;}
```

and XAML code in which I have a ComboBox with something like

```
Text="{Binding name, UpdateSourceTrigger ={Binding trigger}}".
```

How can I accomplish this without any exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use a trigger to change the entire binding.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding trigger}" Value="LostFocus">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding trigger}" Value="PropertyChanged">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Had to change some minor things, but worked with your idea. Thanks a lot.